# How do I prevent map scrolling behind a recycler view?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview, android-maps-v2

In my app I have a fragment where when user taps on search button, a recyclerview opens on top of the map view (covering the whole map view). I am wondering why when there is no data yet in the recyclerview does the map scroll if I am running my finger along the empty recyclerview? Is there a way to prevent the map view behind from scrolling around when the recycler view is open on top, regardless if there is rows loaded in the recycler view yet? Here is the relevant xml:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/mapContainer">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/searchStopsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:visibility="gone">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```